# Accessing a remote database server with python

Tags: python, mysql

Working on this code to collect information off various websites and then send it into a database.  Problem is that I can't seem to connect to the database and not sure what I am doing wrong.  Going to show abridged version of my code of which is just trying to input information and connecting to the database.

```
import pymysql
myConnection = pymysql.connect( host='sql2.njit.edu', user='userID', passwd='password', db='eCubed' )
doQuery( myConnection)
doQuery('Insert INTO eCubed (Date) Values (dateList[i])')
```

So this is what I have.  It saying I am having connection problems.  Again this is just a abridged of my code which involves the database.  I know the rest of my code is fine, I am just working on this part of the code.  Thank you for any insight on what my problem is which is probably a lot ><.

Comment: The problem is if MySQL is listing on a public port (not only localhost) on the server you connect to, and if a firewall rule is blocking access.

Comment: Should I check my firewall settings then and if I should what should I look out for?  How will the public port affect this?

Comment: Look for explicit allow rules or default deny rules. Are the websites on the same LAN as the database? Show `sudo lsof -sTCP:LISTEN  -c mysqld -Pn | grep TCP` on the server?

Comment: Truthfully I do not know.  I barely did any database before so I am extremely  inexperienced with this so sorry for not able to answer these questions properly.

Comment: Well I was talking to an old professor recently, and he said I should have connection as long as I know the id and password and had a vpn activated.  Since I have all 3, I am guessing I did something wrong with my parameters?  Is there a way to check the host and such to see I am getting the right ones?